# Flatten an xml using xsl : problem with elements of grand grand child node

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

I quite new with xmlt, so I guess it is a simple issue.
I want to flatten an xml but intead of having 3 occurences, I have 2 occurences with the second one having repeating elements corresponding to a grand child nodes

Input xml

```
<RL xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="RL.xsd">
  <VERSION>2.3</VERSION>
  <RLM01A>NR110</RLM01A>
  <RLM02A>2019</RLM02A>
  <RLUEx>
    <RL0101>
      <RL0101x>
        <RL0101Ax>7</RL0101Ax>
        <RL0101Ex>CH</RL0101Ex>
        <RL0101Fx>N</RL0101Fx>
        <RL0101Gx>PARC ÉOLIEN</RL0101Gx>
      </RL0101x>
    </RL0101>
    <RL0104>
      <RL0104A>2228</RL0104A>
      <RL0104B>75</RL0104B>
      <RL0104C>6417</RL0104C>
    </RL0104>
    <RL0105A>4812</RL0105A>
    <RL0106A>110015</RL0106A>
    <RL0107A>1100</RL0107A>
    <RL0201>
      <RL0201x>
        <RL0201Ax>PARC ÉOLIEN NICOLAS-RIOU COMMANDITÉ INC.</RL0201Ax>
        <RL0201Cx>1010 DE LA GAUCHETIÈRE OUEST, 20E ÉTAGE</RL0201Cx>
        <RL0201Dx>MONTREAL (QUÉBEC)</RL0201Dx>
        <RL0201Ex>H3B2N2</RL0201Ex>
        <RL0201Fx>BUR. 2000 DÉVELOPPEMENT EDF RENOUVELABLES INC.</RL0201Fx>
        <RL0201Gx>2016-08-08</RL0201Gx>
        <RL0201Hx>2</RL0201Hx>
      </RL0201x>
      <RL0201U>9</RL0201U>
    </RL0201>
    <RL0303A>0</RL0303A>
    <RL0401A>2014-07-01</RL0401A>
    <RL0402A>6000</RL0402A>
    <RL0404A>6000</RL0404A>
    <RL0405A>6000</RL0405A>
    <RL0501A>0</RL0501A>
    <RL0504>
      <RL0504x>
        <RL0504Ax>F-2.1</RL0504Ax>
        <RL0504Bx>204</RL0504Bx>
        <RL0504Cx>7</RL0504Cx>
        <RL0504Dx>6000</RL0504Dx>
        <RL0504Ex>T</RL0504Ex>
        <RL0504Fx>2</RL0504Fx>
      </RL0504x>
      <RL0504x>
        <RL0504Dx>6000</RL0504Dx>
        <RL0504Ex>I</RL0504Ex>
        <RL0504Fx>2</RL0504Fx>
      </RL0504x>
    </RL0504>
  </RLUEx>
  <RLUEx>
    <RL0101>
      <RL0101x>
        <RL0101Ax>8</RL0101Ax>
        <RL0101Ex>CH</RL0101Ex>
        <RL0101Fx>N</RL0101Fx>
        <RL0101Gx>PARC ÉOLIEN</RL0101Gx>
      </RL0101x>
    </RL0101>
    <RL0104>
      <RL0104A>2230</RL0104A>
      <RL0104B>78</RL0104B>
      <RL0104C>8650</RL0104C>
    </RL0104>
    <RL0105A>4812</RL0105A>
    <RL0106A>110016</RL0106A>
    <RL0107A>1100</RL0107A>
    <RL0201>
      <RL0201x>
        <RL0201Ax>PARC ÉOLIEN NICOLAS-RIOU COMMANDITÉ INC.</RL0201Ax>
        <RL0201Cx>1010 DE LA GAUCHETIÈRE OUEST, 20E ÉTAGE</RL0201Cx>
        <RL0201Dx>MONTREAL (QUÉBEC)</RL0201Dx>
        <RL0201Ex>H3B2N2</RL0201Ex>
        <RL0201Fx>BUR. 2000 DÉVELOPPEMENT EDF RENOUVELABLES INC.</RL0201Fx>
        <RL0201Gx>2016-08-08</RL0201Gx>
        <RL0201Hx>2</RL0201Hx>
      </RL0201x>
        <RL0201x>
        <RL0201Ax>FORESTERIE H.B. INC.</RL0201Ax>
        <RL0201Cx>263, RUE J.J. BÉLANGER</RL0201Cx>
        <RL0201Dx>RIVIÈRE-DU-LOUP (QUÉBEC)</RL0201Dx>
        <RL0201Ex>G5R5V9</RL0201Ex>
        <RL0201Fx>BÉRUBÉ HUGO A/S</RL0201Fx>
        <RL0201Gx>2010-10-26</RL0201Gx>
        <RL0201Hx>2</RL0201Hx>
      </RL0201x>
      <RL0201U>9</RL0201U>
    </RL0201>
    <RL0303A>0</RL0303A>
    <RL0401A>2014-07-01</RL0401A>
    <RL0402A>6000</RL0402A>
    <RL0404A>6000</RL0404A>
    <RL0405A>6000</RL0405A>
    <RL0501A>0</RL0501A>
    <RL0504>
      <RL0504x>
        <RL0504Ax>F-2.1</RL0504Ax>
        <RL0504Bx>204</RL0504Bx>
        <RL0504Cx>7</RL0504Cx>
        <RL0504Dx>6000</RL0504Dx>
        <RL0504Ex>T</RL0504Ex>
        <RL0504Fx>2</RL0504Fx>
      </RL0504x>
      <RL0504x>
        <RL0504Dx>6000</RL0504Dx>
        <RL0504Ex>I</RL0504Ex>
        <RL0504Fx>2</RL0504Fx>
      </RL0504x>
    </RL0504>
  </RLUEx>
  <RL0603A>M.R.C. LES BASQUES</RL0603A>
  </RL>
```

here is my xls

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="/RL">
<root>

            <xsl:for-each select="RLUEx">
                <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0101/RL0101x/RL0101Ax"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0101/RL0101x/RL0101Ex"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0101/RL0101x/RL0101Gx"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0103/RL0103x/RL0103Ax"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0105A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0201/RL0201x/RL0201Ax"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0201/RL0201x/RL0201Cx"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0201/RL0201x/RL0201Dx"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0201/RL0201x/RL0201Ex"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0201/RL0201x/RL0201Gx"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0201/RL0201U"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0306/RL0306A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0307/RL0307A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0307/RL0307B"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0308/RL0308A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0309/RL0309A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0310/RL0310A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0311/RL0311A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0312/RL0312A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0313/RL0313A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../RL0603A"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>



</root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here is my output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <RLUEx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RL0101Ax>7</RL0101Ax>
    <RL0101Ex>CH</RL0101Ex>
    <RL0101Gx>PARC Ã‰OLIEN</RL0101Gx>
    <RL0105A>4812</RL0105A>
    <RL0201Ax>PARC Ã‰OLIEN NICOLAS-RIOU COMMANDITÃ‰ INC.</RL0201Ax>
    <RL0201Cx>1010 DE LA GAUCHETIÃˆRE OUEST, 20E Ã‰TAGE</RL0201Cx>
    <RL0201Dx>MONTREAL (QUÃ‰BEC)</RL0201Dx>
    <RL0201Ex>H3B2N2</RL0201Ex>
    <RL0201Gx>2016-08-08</RL0201Gx>
    <RL0201U>9</RL0201U>
    <RL0603A>M.R.C. LES BASQUES</RL0603A>
  </RLUEx>
  <RLUEx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RL0101Ax>8</RL0101Ax>
    <RL0101Ex>CH</RL0101Ex>
    <RL0101Gx>PARC Ã‰OLIEN</RL0101Gx>
    <RL0105A>4812</RL0105A>
    <RL0201Ax>PARC Ã‰OLIEN NICOLAS-RIOU COMMANDITÃ‰ INC.</RL0201Ax>
    <RL0201Ax>FORESTERIE H.B. INC.</RL0201Ax>
    <RL0201Cx>1010 DE LA GAUCHETIÃˆRE OUEST, 20E Ã‰TAGE</RL0201Cx>
    <RL0201Cx>263, RUE J.J. BÃ‰LANGER</RL0201Cx>
    <RL0201Dx>MONTREAL (QUÃ‰BEC)</RL0201Dx>
    <RL0201Dx>RIVIÃˆRE-DU-LOUP (QUÃ‰BEC)</RL0201Dx>
    <RL0201Ex>H3B2N2</RL0201Ex>
    <RL0201Ex>G5R5V9</RL0201Ex>
    <RL0201Gx>2016-08-08</RL0201Gx>
    <RL0201Gx>2010-10-26</RL0201Gx>
    <RL0201U>9</RL0201U>
    <RL0603A>M.R.C. LES BASQUES</RL0603A>
  </RLUEx>
</root>
```

As you can see I have only have 2 occurrences  instead of 3 . In fact, I expect to have an occurence for each grand child of the node /RL0201x/

As you also can see I have problem with the encoding of french characters.
Here is my   desired result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <RLUEx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RL0101Ax>7</RL0101Ax>
    <RL0101Ex>CH</RL0101Ex>
    <RL0101Gx>PARC Ã‰OLIEN</RL0101Gx>
    <RL0105A>4812</RL0105A>
    <RL0201Ax>PARC Ã‰OLIEN NICOLAS-RIOU COMMANDITÃ‰ INC.</RL0201Ax> <RL0201Cx>1010 DE LA GAUCHETIÃˆRE OUEST, 20E Ã‰TAGE</RL0201Cx>   <RL0201Dx>MONTREAL (QUÃ‰BEC)</RL0201Dx>
    <RL0201Ex>H3B2N2</RL0201Ex>
    <RL0201Gx>2016-08-08</RL0201Gx>
    <RL0201U>9</RL0201U>
    <RL0603A>M.R.C. LES BASQUES</RL0603A>
  </RLUEx>
  <RLUEx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RL0101Ax>8</RL0101Ax>
    <RL0101Ex>CH</RL0101Ex>
    <RL0101Gx>PARC Ã‰OLIEN</RL0101Gx>
    <RL0105A>4812</RL0105A>
    <RL0201Ax>PARC Ã‰OLIEN NICOLAS-RIOU COMMANDITÃ‰ INC.</RL0201Ax>
    <RL0201Cx>1010 DE LA GAUCHETIÃˆRE OUEST, 20E Ã‰TAGE</RL0201Cx>
    <RL0201Dx>MONTREAL (QUÃ‰BEC)</RL0201Dx>
    <RL0201Ex>H3B2N2</RL0201Ex>
    <RL0201Gx>2016-08-08</RL0201Gx>
    <RL0201U>9</RL0201U>
    <RL0603A>M.R.C. LES BASQUES</RL0603A>
  </RLUEx>

  <RLUEx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RL0101Ax>8</RL0101Ax>
    <RL0101Ex>CH</RL0101Ex>
    <RL0101Gx>PARC Ã‰OLIEN</RL0101Gx>
    <RL0105A>4812</RL0105A>
    <RL0201Ax>FORESTERIE H.B. INC.</RL0201Ax>
    <RL0201Cx>263, RUE J.J. BÃ‰LANGER</RL0201Cx>
    <RL0201Dx>RIVIÃˆRE-DU-LOUP (QUÃ‰BEC)</RL0201Dx>
    <RL0201Ex>G5R5V9</RL0201Ex>
    <RL0201Gx>2010-10-26</RL0201Gx>
    <RL0201U>9</RL0201U>
    <RL0603A>M.R.C. LES BASQUES</RL0603A>
  </RLUEx>
</root>
```

Here is an updated example for the input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

<RL xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="RL.xsd">
  <VERSION>2.3</VERSION>
  <RLM01A>NR110</RLM01A>
  <RLM02A>2019</RLM02A>
  <RLUEx>
    <RL0101>
      <RL0101x>
        <RL0101Ax>7</RL0101Ax>
        <RL0101Ex>CH</RL0101Ex>
        <RL0101Fx>N</RL0101Fx>
        <RL0101Gx>PARC ÉOLIEN</RL0101Gx>
      </RL0101x>
      <RL0103>
        <RL0103x>
          <RL0103Ax>5955498</RL0103Ax>
         </RL0103x>
      </RL0103>
    </RL0101>
    <RL0104>
      <RL0104A>2228</RL0104A>
      <RL0104B>75</RL0104B>
      <RL0104C>6417</RL0104C>
    </RL0104>
    <RL0105A>4812</RL0105A>
    <RL0106A>110015</RL0106A>
    <RL0107A>1100</RL0107A>
    <RL0201>
      <RL0201x>
        <RL0201Ax>PARC ÉOLIEN NICOLAS-RIOU COMMANDITÉ INC.</RL0201Ax>
        <RL0201Cx>1010 DE LA GAUCHETIÈRE OUEST, 20E ÉTAGE</RL0201Cx>
        <RL0201Dx>MONTREAL (QUÉBEC)</RL0201Dx>
        <RL0201Ex>H3B2N2</RL0201Ex>
        <RL0201Fx>BUR. 2000 DÉVELOPPEMENT EDF RENOUVELABLES INC.</RL0201Fx>
        <RL0201Gx>2016-08-08</RL0201Gx>
        <RL0201Hx>2</RL0201Hx>
      </RL0201x>
      <RL0201U>9</RL0201U>
    </RL0201>
    <RL0303A>0</RL0303A>
    <RL0401A>2014-07-01</RL0401A>
    <RL0402A>6000</RL0402A>
    <RL0404A>6000</RL0404A>
    <RL0405A>6000</RL0405A>
    <RL0501A>0</RL0501A>
    <RL0504>
      <RL0504x>
        <RL0504Ax>F-2.1</RL0504Ax>
        <RL0504Bx>204</RL0504Bx>
        <RL0504Cx>7</RL0504Cx>
        <RL0504Dx>6000</RL0504Dx>
        <RL0504Ex>T</RL0504Ex>
        <RL0504Fx>2</RL0504Fx>
      </RL0504x>
      <RL0504x>
        <RL0504Dx>6000</RL0504Dx>
        <RL0504Ex>I</RL0504Ex>
        <RL0504Fx>2</RL0504Fx>
      </RL0504x>
    </RL0504>
  </RLUEx>
  <RLUEx>
    <RL0101>
      <RL0101x>
        <RL0101Ax>8</RL0101Ax>
        <RL0101Ex>CH</RL0101Ex>
        <RL0101Fx>N</RL0101Fx>
        <RL0101Gx>PARC ÉOLIEN</RL0101Gx>
      </RL0101x>
    </RL0101>
    <RL0103>
      <RL0103x>
        <RL0103Ax>5492043</RL0103Ax>
      </RL0103x>
      <RL0103x>
        <RL0103Ax>5492047</RL0103Ax>
      </RL0103x>
    </RL0103>
    <RL0104>
      <RL0104A>2230</RL0104A>
      <RL0104B>78</RL0104B>
      <RL0104C>8650</RL0104C>
    </RL0104>
    <RL0105A>4812</RL0105A>
    <RL0106A>110016</RL0106A>
    <RL0107A>1100</RL0107A>
    <RL0201>
      <RL0201x>
        <RL0201Ax>PARC ÉOLIEN NICOLAS-RIOU COMMANDITÉ INC.</RL0201Ax>
        <RL0201Cx>1010 DE LA GAUCHETIÈRE OUEST, 20E ÉTAGE</RL0201Cx>
        <RL0201Dx>MONTREAL (QUÉBEC)</RL0201Dx>
        <RL0201Ex>H3B2N2</RL0201Ex>
        <RL0201Fx>BUR. 2000 DÉVELOPPEMENT EDF RENOUVELABLES INC.</RL0201Fx>
        <RL0201Gx>2016-08-08</RL0201Gx>
        <RL0201Hx>2</RL0201Hx>
      </RL0201x>
        <RL0201x>
        <RL0201Ax>FORESTERIE H.B. INC.</RL0201Ax>
        <RL0201Cx>263, RUE J.J. BÉLANGER</RL0201Cx>
        <RL0201Dx>RIVIÈRE-DU-LOUP (QUÉBEC)</RL0201Dx>
        <RL0201Ex>G5R5V9</RL0201Ex>
        <RL0201Fx>BÉRUBÉ HUGO A/S</RL0201Fx>
        <RL0201Gx>2010-10-26</RL0201Gx>
        <RL0201Hx>2</RL0201Hx>
      </RL0201x>
      <RL0201U>9</RL0201U>
    </RL0201>
    <RL0303A>0</RL0303A>
    <RL0401A>2014-07-01</RL0401A>
    <RL0402A>6000</RL0402A>
    <RL0404A>6000</RL0404A>
    <RL0405A>6000</RL0405A>
    <RL0501A>0</RL0501A>
    <RL0504>
      <RL0504x>
        <RL0504Ax>F-2.1</RL0504Ax>
        <RL0504Bx>204</RL0504Bx>
        <RL0504Cx>7</RL0504Cx>
        <RL0504Dx>6000</RL0504Dx>
        <RL0504Ex>T</RL0504Ex>
        <RL0504Fx>2</RL0504Fx>
      </RL0504x>
      <RL0504x>
        <RL0504Dx>6000</RL0504Dx>
        <RL0504Ex>I</RL0504Ex>
        <RL0504Fx>2</RL0504Fx>
      </RL0504x>
    </RL0504>
  </RLUEx>
  <RL0603A>M.R.C. LES BASQUES</RL0603A>
  </RL>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps first select down to the particular element you want to map to a result element, then go up to the ancestor and copy/select what you want to insert:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/RL" priority="5">
      <root>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="RLUEx/RL0201/RL0201x" mode="blue"/>
      </root>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="RL0201x" mode="blue">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::RLUEx">
          <xsl:with-param name="instance" select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="RLUEx" priority="5">
      <xsl:param name="instance"/>
      <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0101/RL0101x/RL0101Ax"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0101/RL0101x/RL0101Ex"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0101/RL0101x/RL0101Gx"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0103/RL0103x/RL0103Ax"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0105A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0201/RL0201x[generate-id() = generate-id($instance)]/RL0201Ax"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0201/RL0201x[generate-id() = generate-id($instance)]/RL0201Cx"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0201/RL0201x[generate-id() = generate-id($instance)]/RL0201Dx"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0201/RL0201x[generate-id() = generate-id($instance)]/RL0201Ex"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0201/RL0201x[generate-id() = generate-id($instance)]/RL0201Gx"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0201/RL0201U"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0306/RL0306A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0307/RL0307A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0307/RL0307B"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0308/RL0308A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0309/RL0309A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0310/RL0310A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0311/RL0311A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0312/RL0312A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="RL0313/RL0313A"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../RL0603A"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or perhaps with the code a bit sanitized:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/RL">
      <root>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="RLUEx/RL0201/RL0201x" mode="blue"/>
      </root>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="RL0201x" mode="blue">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::RLUEx">
          <xsl:with-param name="instance" select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="RLUEx">
      <xsl:param name="instance"/>
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates
            select="RL0101/RL0101x |
                    RL0103/RL0103x/RL0103Ax |
                    RL0105A | 
                    RL0201/RL0201x[generate-id() = generate-id($instance)] |
                    RL0201/RL0201U |
                    RL0306/RL0306A |
                    RL0307/RL0307A |
                    RL0307/RL0307B |
                    RL0309/RL0309A |
                    RL0310/RL0310A |
                    RL0311/RL0311A |
                    RL0312/RL0312A |
                    RL0313/RL0313A |
                    ../RL0603A |
                    RL0103/RL0103x/RL0103Ax
                    "/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="RL0101x">
      <xsl:copy-of
        select="RL0101Ax | RL0101Ex | RL0101Gx"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="RL0201x">
      <xsl:copy-of 
        select="RL0201Cx | RL0201Dx | RL0201Ex | RL0201Gx"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but i just discovered that another node can by multiple: RL0103 and I need  to have RL0103Ax from this node in the flattened xml.
I added the updated input example in the main post (because I don't have enough space in the comment space). So
Is it possible to add an id in the flattend

Comment: @MoujahedHadj-Taieb, it doesn't make much sense to post a question with certain input data and requirements to later change the data and the requirements after an answer was posted and accepted. Perhaps first try to see whether you can resolve the new problem on your own, if not, raise it in a new question. As with any samples, try to show minimal samples to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but i just discovered that another node can by multiple: RL0103 and I need  to have RL0103Ax from this node in the flattened xml.
I added the updated input example in the main post (because I don't have enough space in the comment space). 
So the output from this updated input must have 5 occurences: 1*1+2*2
Also,  is it possible to add an id in the flattened XML for the main node RL (because I have to load multiple files) and the nodes: (<RLUEx>) and RL0103x and RL0201x